# Consume WCF from unity3D

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-game-engine

I have some wcf webservices that i host in IIS on localhost.
I want to be able to access them from Unity3d but i get the following error when i play the scene :

```
InvalidOperationException: Client endpoint configuration 'BasicHTTPEndpoint' was not found in 0 endpoints.
System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration (System.String endpointConfig)
System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint (System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[IUnityStore]..ctor (System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel].Initialize (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.String endpointConfigurationName)
System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[TChannel]..ctor (System.String endpointConfigurationName)
UnityStoreClient..ctor (System.String endpointConfigurationName)
firstCall.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/firstCall.cs:8)
```

The webservice is instantiated like :

```
UnityStoreClient uc = new UnityStoreClient("BasicHTTPEndpoint");
uc.Open(); //i don't know if i need this ?????
UnityStoreLibrary.User[] users = uc.GetAllUsers("1",null);
for (int i=0;i<users.Length;i++)
    Debug.Log("username = " + users[i].username);
```

I have a config file in my scripts folder but i don't know if i should make something with it. I created the unity class with `svcutil` from Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> using System.ServiceModel;

this statement was missing from my class implementation.

I called the webservice like this :

```
UnityStoreClient client = new UnityStoreClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(some_url));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the exception message gives you a hint about what is missing.

The ConfigurationManager cannot find any details related to your WCF service in the  section of the web.config file.

The details about the WCF service you are calling should be stored in the web.config file. There should be an endpoint definition like this in your web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint name="BasicHTTPEndpoint"
      address="http://myUnits3DService.svc"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="IService"/>
 ...
```

Maybe you should also check the details about using svcutil.exe from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

Comment: where should i place this web.config file ?

Comment: It should be placed in the same directory with the assembly that you make the webservice call.

Comment: The class that i generated with `svcutil` is in Scripts\ClientProxies. I also have Plugins directory with some dll's in it : System.Runtime.Serialization, System.Security, System.ServiceModel. Where is the assembly directory ? My config file is called web.config.